# git - date at which commits were pulled into repository

Tags: git

I know from my server logs that an error first starts appearing at a certain time many days ago.

To deploy, I issue a `git pull` on my server.
I want to find out what commits were pulled around the time the errors started to show up.

Looking at the logs, the `<author date>` and `<committer date>` both give the same date across all repositories (as you'd expect), and they relate to when the commit was committed to git (in the development repository), not when it appeared in the deployment repository.

Any idea if it's possible to tease out this info from git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
git reflog show master@{2.weeks.ago}
```

Comment: does it show all the commits? As per the manual - `master@{one.week.ago} means "where master used to point to one week ago",` so the inbetween commits cannot be seen right?

Comment: This looks promising! Will prob accept once I understand what the output means :)

Comment: Good point @manojlds.  Once you make a note of the commit, you can use `git log commit..` to see everything pulled in since then.

Answer (score 1):

I too want to know a good answer for this, but one thing I can suggest is, get the hash of a commit, go to `.git/objects/xx/remaininghash` and see the date at which it was created?

I am not directly answering your question, but you can also use `git bisect` to narrow down which commit caused the problem.

Comment: great answer - I'm getting a nice list of commits using:
`find .git/objects/ -mtime N-DAYS -type f |xargs ls -al`

Comment: Ok, now who downvoted and why? Even the OP was mildly happy with it!